# TestEngine with ID 'junit-jupiter' failed to discover tests while debugging

Tags: java, testing, junit5, junit-jupiter

I noticed that problem with Junit5 when I'm trying to debug the code. Anyone faced that issue? I've tried to change the version etc but nothing has helped.

My pom.xml:

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>18</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>18</maven.compiler.target>
    <restassured.version>5.1.1</restassured.version>
 </properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
        <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
        <version>${restassured.version}</version>
    </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Stacktrace:

```
org.junit.platform.commons.JUnitException: TestEngine with ID 'junit-jupiter' failed to discover tests
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.discoverEngineRoot(EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.java:160)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.discoverSafely(EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.java:134)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.discover(EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.discover(EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discover(DefaultLauncher.java:110)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
```

Comment: What do your Test class(es) look like?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some IntelliJ update overwrote Instrumenting agent.
To solve that problem:

1. Go to Preferences/Settings
2. Build, Execution, Deployment
3. Debugger
4. Async Stack Trances

then check Instrumenting agent is enabled. It should be disabled.